# Deploying .NET Core Microservices

Tags: c#, microservices

Looking into using .NET Core in a microservice architecture however I’m seeing a lot of examples that are all using Docker to host the service. Is this absolutely necessary especially when deploying on Linux? With Java I can just create an executable jar and create a start/run script on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly it's not necessary, but it can make management simpler, and keep your service portable.

With docker, you don't need to know anything about the server hosting it. You include all your dependencies in your Dockerfile, which is included with you source package.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, but highly recommended .. Check out this article: [Advantages of Using Docker for Microservices](https://rubygarage.org/blog/advantages-of-using-docker-for-microservices)

Summarizing the article: Docker offers the following:

> 1. Faster start time
> 2. Faster deployment
> 3. Easier management and scaling
> 4. Better usage of computing resources
> 5. Support for various operating systems